# Android, "more details" UI best practice?

Tags: android, user-interface

I need to show some data to my user, in my Android app, which fit on one page; and, I want to give her the possibility to show "more details", i.e. more data.
In my situation I have some textviews inside a vertical scrollview inside a relative layout.
Is there a "best practice", or a recommendation, or just something you like - to implement the "more details" user control? To show an icon, a button, some text, ...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, a button saying "More Details" would be fine, then just hide the button and show more details where the button was, at the end of the scroll view.